# Convertir objeto a json en view de django rest framework

Tags: python, json, objeto, djangorestframework

Tengo una vista en django rest framework que me permite generar un pdf, quiero obtener los datos desde models, tengo esta función en `views.py`:

```
def generaPdf(request):
    
    stu = models.ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.objects.filter(id_user=4)
    serializer = ConfiguracionCv_PersonalizadoSerializer(stu, many=True)
    print(serializer.data)
    json_data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)

    
    # PDF = generapdf.PDF
    pdf = PDF()
    pdf.alias_nb_pages()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Times', '', 11)
    for k, v in json_data.items():
        pdf.cell(0, 10, f"{k}: {v}", 0, 1)
    pdf = pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1')
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf"'
    return(response)
```

En `serializers.py` tengo esto:

```
class ConfiguracionCv_PersonalizadoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado
        fields = ('__all__')
```

Estoy tratando de convertir `models.ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.objects` a json para recorrerlo en el for y agregar la información al pdf, pero recibo este error `'bytes' object has no attribute 'items'`. Como puedo hacer convertir el `models.ConfiguracionCv_Personalizado.objects` a json y poder recorrerlo en el for. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el json no se puede recorrer directamente como lo mencionas , para recorrerlo debes primero convertirlo en un diccionario el cual python si entiende, recuerda que aunque el json se parezca al diccionario son objetos distintos por lo que json no lo puedes recorrer directamente con un ciclo for
Utiliza esta línea

json_data=json.loads(json_data)

justo después de la linea. Jsonrenderer()....etc
json_data con tu código actual, ya es un objeto json pero aún no es un objeto diccionario para poderse recorrer con tu ciclo for por lo que esta linea convierte json_data en un diccionario y así podrás iterarlo